# ER Diagram Entity that does not have to be a member of another entity

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship, diagram

So I am trying to create an ER diagram. Although, I just ran into a problem. It states that "Assume each student is assigned to one academic advisor, but an advisor advises many students. advisors do not have to be faculty members." And I am struggling with the last part. Does this mean that 'Advisor' has to be its own entity now? I have a picture describing what I am asking :

[image: ER Diagram]

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct. If Advisor isn't a subtype of Faculty, then you can handle it as a distinct entity set. However, I would model Student, Advisor and Faculty as subtypes of Person, so that common attributes can be declared once and so that overlapping subtypes don't cause multiple different identifiers for the same person.